# how to make a screen identify which screen user came from?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have three screens, Screen A, Screen B and Screen C. If the user press a button in Screen A or Screen B, it will direct them to Screen C. I want Screen C to detect which screen the user came from. If the user came from Screen A, the background color of Screen C will be red. If the user came from Screen B, the background color of Screen C will be blue. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the route name in the navigation parameters when you press the button :

```
navigation.navigate("screen c", {cameFrom: "A"})
```

and in the screen C you apply the color according to the route parameter

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: route.params.cameFrom === 'A' ? 'red' : 'blue'}}> 
... 
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables by adding an extra option in the navigation function. And get them through the route props. There is a detailed guide in the [react-navigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/).

```js
    function Screen1({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              // extra option in your nativigate function 
              navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
                yourValue: '123',
              })
            }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
      
    function Screen2({ route, navigation }) {
      //get the value here
      const { yourValue } = route.params;
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have navigation stack already installed in your code. If not installed then install [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/). After that define your navigation stack like below:-

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen
            name="AScreen"
            component={AScreenComponentName}
            options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false, title: 'AScreen',}}
          />
<Stack.Screen
            name="BScreen"
            component={BScreenComponentName}
            options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false, title: 'BScreen',}}
          />
<Stack.Screen
            name="CScreen"
            component={CScreenComponentName}
            options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false, title: 'CScreen',}}
          />
  </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

Now if you want to navigate to any screen eg on any button tap then use below code

> if using functional component then use below:-

```
navigation.navigate(Ascreen)
```

> if using class component then use below:-

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(Ascreen)
```

Comment: I need Screen C to detect which screen the user came from. How do I achieve that?

Comment: This is no answering the Q.